# Duplicate last row of a table in LibreOffice using BASIC

Tags: vba, libreoffice, libreoffice-basic, libreoffice-writer

I have a named table in a ODT document and want to duplicate the last row with all content into a new row (above), then replace some value in this duplicate.

I've done this in Word/VBA already for DOCX:

```
Dim tbl As Table
Dim rowNew As Row

Set tbl = ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
Set rowNew = tbl.Rows.Add(tbl.Rows(tbl.Rows.Count))
rowNew.Range.FormattedText = tbl.Rows(tbl.Rows.Count).Range.FormattedText
'~~~> This is required as the above code inserts a blank row in between
tbl.Rows(tbl.Rows.Count - 1).Delete
rowNew.Select
Selection.Find.Execute FindText:="xx*", ReplaceWith:="bar", MatchWildcards:=True
Selection.Collapse
```

Is this also possible in LibreOffice? So far, I have:

```
DIM tbl As Variant
DIM row As Variant
tbl =  ThisComponent.getTextTables().getByIndex(0)
row = tbl.getRows().getByIndex(tbl.getRows().getCount()-1)
```

How can I select and duplicate the whole **row** and run search&replace on this new row? Hint: the row may contain other objects like subtables.

Answer (score 1):

First select the entire row by moving the [View Cursor](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Writer/API/View_cursor) over it.  Then use the dispatcher to copy and paste into a new row.  Something like this:

```vb
oVC.goRight(3, True)  'Extend the selection.
dispatcher = createUnoService("com.sun.star.frame.DispatchHelper")
dispatcher.executeDispatch(document, ".uno:Copy", "", 0, Array())
dispatcher.executeDispatch(document, ".uno:InsertRowsAfter", "", 0, Array())
oVC.goDown(1, False)  'Move to the new row.
oVC.goLeft(2, False)  'Move to the first column.
dispatcher.executeDispatch(document, ".uno:Paste", "", 0, Array())
```